# Is there a way to (automatically) separate devDependencies from dependencies in an existing package.json?

Tags: node.js, json, npm, dependencies, package.json

I have a package.json with dozens of packages in the "dependencies" section, some of which I know are actually devDependencies and many of which I have no idea.

Is there an easy way to automatically move devDependencies into their own "devDependencies" section without having to manually google each package and see if the docs say to save `--dev` or not?

I see many topics discussing the differences between the two (which I understand), but I'm trying sort out an existing package.json where the packages are all lumped into the dependencies section.

Comment: No, there's no way to automate that. Whether a given dependency is dev or prod depends partly on context.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It would be a great online tool for someone to develop... you paste in your package.json and it splits into dependencies and devDependencies. It would take a lot of work to build the database though.

Comment: For the reason I've already mentioned, though, it wouldn't work. *Context* matters. Compare https://github.com/textbook/react-ts-fe and https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit, for example; front-end deps are prod in one and dev in the other. Or what about utility libraries that could be used from production or test code?

Comment: you could brute force the method though - however that might take a while